# How do you set MVCSitemapnode roles property on page load?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

So I have an mvcsitemap:

```
<mvcSiteMapNode id="Home" title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Page2" controller="Page2" action="Index"/>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Page3" controller="Page3" action="Index" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Page4" controller="Pag4" action="Index" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

What I want to do is when the site is loaded I want to set the "Roles" attribute of each node inividually from values from a database. Example:

I want the Home node to be accessible from the roles: Admin, User
I want the Page2 node to be accessible from the roles: User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming#interoperability-with-aspnet), the roles attribute is for iteroperability with ASP.NET. It is not supposed to be used for MVC security, primarily because MVC doesn't secure physical pages, but instead MVC secures *resources* (usually controller actions). The ASP.NET security scheme is based on the underlying file system and as a result is completely inadequate for use with MVC.

MVC security is based on the [`AuthorizeAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). You can subclass `AuthorizeAttribute` to provide any security scheme you need, including reading settings from the database on each round trip if that is what you really want. See [this article](http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2011/07/24/writing-your-own-custom-aspnet-mvc-authorize-attributes) for one such approach.

But do note that the default `AuthorizeAttribute` implementation supports roles and users on controller actions, which would be a better performing solution.

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrators,SuperUsers")]
public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePasswordModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Once you base your security on `AuthorizeAttribute` (or a subclass of `AuthorizeAttribute`), `MvcSiteMapProvider` will automatically interact with it. The only thing you need to do is [turn on security trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming#enabling-security-trimming).

Internal DI (web.config)

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MvcSiteMapProvider_SecurityTrimmingEnabled" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

External DI (MvcSiteMapProvider Module)

```
bool securityTrimmingEnabled = true; // Near the top of the module
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure if it what you looking but can you just do a condition in your view ?? like this

```
 @if (this.User.IsInRole("Admin")){ <mvcSiteMapNode title="Page2"
 controller="Page2" action="Index"/>} else
 if(this.User.IsInRole("User"))....
```

Comment: I was trying to control it from the database and not hard-code any values since the pages specific roles have access to can change rather frequently.